# Creative Mode Permissions Node(s)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

Is there a permissions node to disable a player from being in creative mode?

*Read: Not one that disallows access to /gamemode, but one that would prevent /gamemode from changing a players mode.*

If there is not a built in one, does anyone know of a plugin that does this?

At the very least I would like a *permission node* that disallows flying while in creative mode.

I have searched the bukkit plugins site, for 'creative', and have seen all of those.

Comment: I'm a little confused... how is a plugin that prevents /gamemode from changing a player's mode any different from one that just disallows the use of /gamemode?

Comment: Sometimes game mode can be changed by the server, rather than a person using the /gamemode command.  In my case, I have Multiworld running, and when you are tp'd into it, the default is to change everyone's mode to creative.  I would like to limit this automatic with permission groups, or at the very least, disable flying with a permissions node.

Comment: Another situation I could think of, is that some of your mods have /gamemode, but you would like to block certain players from having that command used on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such plugin exists, so I made a quick and dirty custom one I call ModeLock. You can download it [here](http://imjake9.tk/download/ModeLock/jar/1.0), which should in theory work with all future versions of Bukkit unless something drastic changes.

It will by default block all gamemode changes for all players. To allow a player change into the creative gamemode, give them the permission node `modelock.creative`. To allow them to become survival, give them `modelock.survival`. To give them both, you can use `modelock.gamemode`.

Comment: Cool, except.. I'm running 1.1-R4 and this doesn't seem to have any effect with or without permissions set.  It's not actually blocking mode changes done by the server nor is it blocking changes done by a user using /gamemode.  If you want to set it up to send debug messages, I'll give it another try?

Comment: @bitfed Whoops, my bad. Should work fine now, just redownload it.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Jake. Mode changes are prohibited now!  I've not actually tested the permissions yet, I will do that now, but have marked this as an answer.

Comment: I have another question... I presume that I can use modelock.* in my Perms manager?

Comment: Feature Request (Already, lol): Permissions node for disabling flight while in creative mode?

Comment: @bitfed Sadly, there's currently no way in Bukkit to keep creative mode but disable flight. I'm working with the Bukkit team to get that fixed, though, so stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is `/creative` in Essentials. You can then get the [Essentials GroupManager](http://wiki.ess3.net/wiki/Group_Manager). Then, look up the `/creative` permission node, and add it to the group you want it using

`/mangaddp (group) (permission node)`

on console or in-game.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in vanilla using the following command set on a fast clock. It basically tests for players in creative mode and switches them to survival.

> /execute @a[m=1] /gamemode 0 @a